# How to call JS function with jQuery using animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using animate.css library.

I have this Javascript function

```
function animationClick(element, animation){
element = $(element);
element.click(
    function() {
        element.addClass('animated ' + animation);
        window.setTimeout( function(){
            element.removeClass('animated ' + animation);
        }, 600);         

    });

}
```

I have this jQuery call

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#startButton").click(function() {
    animationClick(this, 'pulse');
});

});
```

This is my html

```
<input id="startButton" class="btn contained animated fadeInDown" type="button" id="startButton" value="Start!"></input>
```

What i have tried, i have tried adding `onclick=""` to my html button, and calling the function directly, nothing seemed to work.

I thought something was wrong with the animation, so i tried to do a simple `.hide` instead but my jQuery still hasn't worked

I've looked online and made sure my pages are calling each other properly, such as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="animation.css">` and `<script src="play.js"></script>`

I have also tried to import jQuery versions by downloading it locally and calling the file `<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`
Help appreciated

**An update:**

I have checked the page console and this message appears: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at play.js:92`
Line 92 is `$(document).ready(function () {`
I'm thinking this is an importing of jQuery issue, but i have already imported it. Isn't the import correct?

Comment: What argument did you insert inside `onclick=""`?

Comment: I have called a JS function and tried adding the parameters, and also tried a different function which worked but had no jQuery

Comment: Do you mean you inserted something like `onclick="animationClick(this, 'pulse')"`, didn't you?

Comment: I have tried that yes, also tried calling another function not relevant to the code above which worked find, so i know `onclick` is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("click","#startButton",function() {
    $(this).addClass('animated pulse');
        window.setTimeout( function(){
            $(this).removeClass('animated pulse');
     }, 600);    
});
});
```

No need to call a function you can add and remove class directly on click event of jQuery!!

Comment: That's interesting, i hadn't thought of this. However my button didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Are you adding this button dynamically? Using AJAX?

Comment: No, it is in my `div` which is in my `body` inside my html file

Comment: Are you getting any error in console? BTW I have updated my code check if it works?

Comment: Yes, i updated the question with the error, it is pointing to the line i start the `$` jQuery

Comment: Make sure you have imported jQuery.min.js before play.js in your html.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#startButton").on("click", function() {
   $(this).addClass('animated pulse');
        window.setTimeout( function(){
        $(this).removeClass('animated pulse');
   }, 600);    
 });

</script>
```

This is how your code should look, maybe your loading your jquery after your dom function.

Comment: I am loading the jQuery within the `<head>` and before the `<body>`

Comment: No need to use dom ready function, once you click on the button the class will be added to the element when the click event is fired. You can also use jQuery instead of $, just replace and check.

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle for your refernce you can clearly see that the class is added once you click on the button : https://jsfiddle.net/22hdfh1w/4/